# UI tabs of jQuery get disordered

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery tabs. When I load my home page it loads properly. But after clicking on some other tab and come back to my main tab again, those tags get disordered.

Can any one please answer this question.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Please, improve your question. Put some code so people can help you. Also, consider to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask